# Ranking in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ranking

I want to create a ranking of users. It should sort users descending by count of added events.

That's my files:

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  #...
end
```

ranking.html.erb:

```
<tr>
    <% User.all.each  do |user| %> 
    <td> <%= user.name %></td>
    <td> <%= user.events_count %></br></td> 
<% end %>
 </tr>
```

schema.rb:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  #...
  t.integer  "events_count", default: 0
end
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to use a counter cache.

`Event.rb`:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
end
```

`ranking.html.erb`:

```
<tr>
  <% User.order(events_count: :desc).each do |user| %>
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I want :)